# Can't add new SpecFlow item in Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, specflow

I installed SpecFlow package via NuGet in VS2012 Express edition for my class library project.
But when I want to add a new SpecFlow item to it I can't find any SpecFlow templates on the list.
I see in the project references that TechTalk.SpecFlow is added.

I found some work around for VS2010 Express : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041703/1037754 but I would prefer to have it working in the 'normal' way if possible:)

I have .Net 4.5 on my machine if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express does not support project extensions (forbidden and disabled by Microsoft).

This means you cannot use the SpecFlow Gherkin Editor (syntax highlighting, table formatting, autocomplete for steps, navigation between steps and step definition code), nor does the code generation from feature files to executable scenarios work from the IDE (single file generator).

However you can edit feature files as normal text files and you can generate the executable scenarios using the SpecFlow command line tool (like you would do on the build server).

Comment: Thanks.I thought that if I'm able to add it via NuGet it should be ready to use.