# Visual studio professional 2013 for specflow tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-build-professional

Sorry for this question as i am very new to Visual studio with c# knowledge.
I am single tester in organization.

The requirement is i need to test an application using Visual studio 2013 with Specflow features. My workaround is that i need to buy standalone Licence for Visual studio professional 2013, so that i can use specflow. (I already tried running tests in visual studio EXPRESS but specflow extensions are not supported). Are there any restrictions for standalone licence? Please correct me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747538/specflow-with-visual-studio-express

Comment: Hi Martin. Thats not me who downvoted. Even my question has been downvoted. Not sure why.

Comment: Dear @L-Four. Thanks for the link. I have already gone through this question when i posted this. It didnt help at all. My requirement is for specflow features. Even the answers for the link didnt help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, VS 2013 Express does not support extensions. So working within SpecFlow will prove difficult. http://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2014/05/07/visual-studio-express-edition-doesn-t-support-extensions-despite-its-extension-manager/

Is there any reason it has to be 2013? I'd recommend downloading a copy of the 2015 Community edition - which is free and supports extensions.

Comment: HI Martin, 

Yes you are right. Express edition doesnt support any extensions.

Comment: Also i am using 2015 edition of trail premium version. its valid for 3 months.

Comment: And it supports all the extensions for the testing which i require, specially specflow extensions.