# SpecFlow: ClassInitialize and TestContext

Tags: c#, mstest, visual-studio-2012, specflow

first of all I'm new to SpecFlow.

I have a feature file which I have / want to automate using MSTest to run as a functional test involving a fully set up server, data access ...
For this purpose I have to configure the server with the data in the SpecFlow's 'Given' blocks and start it afterwards. I also have to copy some files to the test's output directory.

In the non-SpecFlow functional tests I was using the ClassInitialize attribute to get the TestDeploymentDir from the TestContext; something like this:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassSetup(TestContext context)
{
  TargetDataDeploymentRoot = context.TestDeploymentDir;
}
```

Now with SpecFlow I can't use this attribute anymore as it is used by SpecFlow itself.
Some new attributes do exist, like *BeforeFeature* which acts similarly BUT it doesn't pass on the TestContext as a parameter.

I just need to get access to the TestContext's TestDeploymentDir in order to copy some files there before really lauching my functional test server - easily doable without SpecFlow but almost impossible with SpecFlow.

How to deal with this issue?

Is it possible at all?

Thanks a lot for advice!

robert

---

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2012
- SpecFlow 1.9.0.77

Comment: You can generate MSTest tests from your feature fiels with specflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984318/how-to-run-specflow-tests-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm already generating MSTest tests from my feature files, but as mentioned above, the I have no access to the TestContext.

Comment: Maybe the [AssemblyInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute(v=vs.80).aspx) can work for your scenario, specflow don't use it. Otherwise with the current `MsTestGeneratorProvider` generated feature files you cannot get the provied `TestContext`. However you can derive from `MsTestGeneratorProvider` and generate tests which stores the `TestContext` somewhere inside specflow.

Comment: Thanks for advice. It definitely sounds good - I'll give it a try soon.

Comment: Where do I find this MsTestGeneratorProvider? Can you maybe provide an example?

Answer (score 5):

Since SpecFlow 2.2.1 the TestContext is available via Context Injection. (https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/882)

You can get it from the container directly:

`ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioContainer.Resolve<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext>()`

or via context injection:

```
public class MyStepDefs
{
    private readonly TestContext _testContext;
    public MyStepDefs(TestContext testContext) // use it as ctor parameter
    { 
        _testContext = testContext;
    }

    [BeforeScenario()]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        //now you can access the TestContext
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to have access to values in the TestContext you have to create partial class for each scenario file you have in which you add the .

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

/// <summary>
/// Partial class for TestContext support.
/// </summary>
public partial class DistributionFeature
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test execution context.
    /// </summary>
    private TestContext testContext;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets test execution context.
    /// </summary>
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return this.testContext;
        }

        set
        {
            this.testContext = value;

            //see https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/96
            this.TestInitialize();
            FeatureContext.Current["TestContext"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could access the deployment directory from your steps using

```
var testContext = (TestContext)FeatureContext.Current["TestContext"];
var deploymentDir = testContext.TestDeploymentDir;
```

If you have too many scenarios, then you probably has to automate creation of such files with T4.

Comment: If you are using this technique, when you upgrade to SpecFlow 2.2.1, you need to amend things slightly.  Have a look here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/936

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Plugin and customize the IUnitTestGeneratorProvider implementation. The following should add the line to MSTest's class initialize.

```
// It's very important this is named Generator.SpecflowPlugin.
namespace MyGenerator.Generator.SpecflowPlugin
{
    public class MyGeneratorProvider : MsTest2010GeneratorProvider
    {
        public MyGeneratorProvider(CodeDomHelper codeDomHelper)
            : base(codeDomHelper)
        {
        }

         public override void SetTestClassInitializeMethod(TestClassGenerationContext generationContext)
        {

            base.SetTestClassInitializeMethod(generationContext);

generationContext.TestClassInitializeMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement(
                                                                      @"TargetDataDeploymentRoot = context.TestDeploymentDir;"));

        }

     }


[assembly: GeneratorPlugin(typeof(MyGeneratorPlugin))]

    public class MyGeneratorPlugin : IGeneratorPlugin
    {
        public void RegisterDependencies(ObjectContainer container)
        {
        }

        public void RegisterCustomizations(ObjectContainer container, SpecFlowProjectConfiguration generatorConfiguration)
        {
            container.RegisterTypeAs<MyGeneratorProvider, IUnitTestGeneratorProvider>();
        }

        public void RegisterConfigurationDefaults(SpecFlowProjectConfiguration specFlowConfiguration)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

And reference it in the App.config file:

```
<specFlow>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MyGenerator" type="Generator"/>
    </plugins>
 </specFlow>
```

Next time you re-save the .feature files the generated code in ClassInitialize should set the TargetDataDeploymentDirectory.

I had to do something similar. Here's my working code https://github.com/marksl/Specflow-MsTest and blog post  http://codealoc.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/bdding-with-specflow/

Answer (score -1):

> There is a FeatureContext as well as the more commonly used
>   ScenarioContext. The difference of course is that the FeatureContext
>   exists during the execution of the complete feature while the
>   ScenarioContext only exists during a scenario.

For example:

Add to context:

```
ScenarioContext.Current.Add("ObjectName", myObject);
```

Get:

```
var myObject = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<object>("ObjectName");
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/FeatureContext).

Comment: Good morning, I've seen that and it would be fine IF I could my TestContext's property in there. How would this be possible? That's a blocking issue for me! Thanks a lot for advice, robert