# Programmatically access Test Results file tsr file name/path

Tags: c#, mstest

Could anyone please help me with programmaticaly accessing the TSR file name and path generated by MS Test ?

I'm trying to generate a html report at the end of the test run and I need access to the tsr file to generate the html.

Answer (score 0):

The TestContext Class provides information about the test results directory.

How to create and access Test Context property can be found in

[SpecFlow: ClassInitialize and TestContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218020/specflow-classinitialize-and-testcontext)